# how to implement makeTextLarger method in webview iphone

Tags: iphone, webview

i have a webview with 2 buttons text plus and text minus.when i click on text plus, text size should be increased.how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This question actually has nothing to do with iPhone or `UIWebView` *per se* -- it's a standard Web dev question. The solution is pretty straightforward: use JavaScript to install a click handler for the button that increases the value of the text in your CSS. For more detailed answers, just search for the the same topic here on Stack Overflow, but without the iphone tag.